# calling ColdFusion.Ajax.submitform() multiple times in a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a page that has multiple forms on it. I then have a button that it has a jQuery click event handler attached to it that calls ColdFusion.Ajax.submitform() for each form. My problem is that the submitform() only works for some of the forms on the page. The rest of the forms do not get saved. To note: I can save all of the forms individually so I know that it is not a problem with my "form action" code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#saveAll").click(function() {
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form1', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form2', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form3', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form4', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form5', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form6', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form7', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
        });
    });

    location.href = 'http://localhost/multipleforms.cfm';
</script>
```

When I removed the 'location.href' line all the forms are saved. Does anybody know why that line would cause not all the forms to be saved? The reason 'location.href' is there is because I would like to refresh the page so that the user can see the data that is dependent on the values they picked in the form; and I don't want to use 'location.reload()' because it always produces a pop-up window confirming the reload. Also to note, I am trying to avoid using one big form to save the form data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `A` in Ajax. You're asynchronously submitting seven forms, but each submission could return at any time, and in any order. What happens if form five takes a minute to return because the server is stalled?

Another problem you'll encounter is that browsers typically allow between two and six simultaneous requests, so despite the asynchronous nature of the calls, the browser may stall waiting for a connection.

If your application depends on the simultaneous ajax submission of seven forms, one option would be to try to refactor the app so you're making one ajax submission with dynamic parameters selected from all the forms in question.

If that's not possible, another approach would be to chain the seven requests, with each request triggered inside the *callback* of its predecessor. Something like this:

```
 ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form1', 'multipleforms.cfm', function(){
   ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form2', 'multipleforms.cfm', function(){
     ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form3', 'multipleforms.cfm', function(){
       // etc
     });
   });
 });
```

Here we have a cascade of submissions, each firing when the previous one is complete. If your redirection can't occur until `form7` is submitted, that redirection would be inside the callback of the final submission:

```
 // forms 1 through 6, then inside the callback of form6:
 ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form7', 'multipleforms.cfm', function(){
   location.replace('http://localhost/multipleforms.cfm'); // fires last
 });
```

With any approach that could stall the browser, the very first thing you should do is pop up a spinner or progress message so the user understands the app is working. With the chained approach, you could even update a progress bar as each stage is completed.

A final more brute-force option would be to make the calls *synchronous*. [Check out the `asynch` argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7ffe.html). Of course this *will* lead to a stall before the redirect, so refactoring is probably the best option from the user experience perspective.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine :). I completely forgot about the callbackHandler argument of Ajax.submitForm.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it may be a matter of the submitForm happening through an asynchronous request, so your location.href is happening before all of the forms are actually submitted and processed. Try changing the location.href line to this, and place it inside the click declaration so that it happens after the last submitForm call:

```
ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm( 'form7', 'multipleforms.cfm' );
window.setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = 'http://localhost/multipleforms.cfm';
}, 0);
```

That should prevent the location.href from firing before all of the previous events have processed.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `asynch` attribute to false, to prevent asynchronous submissions.

Alternatively if you used a normal jQuery ajax submission, you can use the `complete` setting to make sure subsequent form submissions only happen once the previous one completes succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted this as a comment, but it is too long.

To clean up Ken and Dan's code you could write the following script

```
(function(){
     var valueArray = split(commaSeparatedValueList,",");
     for(var i=0; i<valueArray.length; i++){
          if((i+1) < 7)last = false;
          else last = true;
          submitForm('form'+(i+1), last);
     }
});
function submitForm(formid,last){
     ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm(formId=formid, URL='multipleforms.cfm',asynch=false, callback=function(){
          if(last)location.href = 'http://localhost/multipleforms.cfm';
     });
}
```

I am no master of JavaScript, but that should in theory work.  It submits the form synchronously so you don't have to worry about one getting hung up.